# Socket Server Memory usage goes up, becomes unresponsive

Tags: c, linux, sockets, memory-leaks, pthreads

I have the following socket server code for Linux using Pthreads.

If I start stress testing this with:

```
for ((;;)); do echo STAT | nc 127.0.0.1 5555 ; done
```

The memory increases to about 270MB then the server becomes unresponsive:

```
271688 ./test
```

On ARMv7 architecture this takes a shorter time. If I stop the requests with the *for* loop, the memory does not get freed up, meaning that this server would sooner or later crash anyway in production.

Compiles with:

```
$ gcc -lpthread -o test test.c
```

What can be the problem in the following code?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char *Match(const char *instr, const char *pattern) {
    const char *p, *q;
    for (; *instr; instr++) {
        for (p = instr, q = pattern; *p && *q; p++, q++)
            if (*p != *q) break;
        if (p == q || *q == 0) return (char *)instr;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *connection_handler2(void *socket_desc) {
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int comm, i;
    int read_size;
    char *message, client_message[500], data[50];
    char buf[256];

    strcpy(data, "Test message back");

    message = "Hello this is test Server\n";
    write(sock, message, strlen(message));

    while ((read_size = recv(sock, client_message, 500, 0)) > 0) {
        if (Match(client_message, "STAT") != NULL) {
            write(sock, data, strlen(data));
        }
        if (Match(client_message, "QUIT") != NULL) break;
    }

    if (read_size == 0) {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    } else
    if (read_size == -1) {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    close(sock);
    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}

void *s2_thread() {
    int n, i;
    int opt = 1;
    int socket_desc, client_sock, c, *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    struct termios toptions;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        printf(" Could not create socket");
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(5555);
    //bind the socket to the address
    setsockopt(socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *)&opt, sizeof(int));

    //Bind
    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        //print the error message
        perror("port 5000 bind failed");
        return;
    }     
    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc, 3);

    //Accept
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //Endless main loop
    while ((client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c))) {
        pthread_t t2;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;

        if (pthread_create(&t2, NULL,  connection_handler2, (void*)new_sock) < 0) {
            return;
        }
    }

    if (client_sock < 0) {
        return;
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, i;
    int opt = 1;
    int socket_desc, client_sock, c, *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    pthread_t ss2t;

    if (pthread_create(&ss2t, NULL, s2_thread,  NULL) < 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Telnet server started");

    while (1) sleep(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works on ARMv7 in general. You mean ARMv7**A**? Or ARMv7**R**? Very likely not ARMv7**M**! And why do you thing this is a problem of the architecture? Very unlikely for application level code. Re. the code: See [ask], provide a [mcve]. This is no debugging service.

Comment: `new_sock = malloc(1);` don't you mean `new_sock = malloc(sizeof(int));`

Comment: Removing `const` qualifier for `instr` in `Match` is a **very** bad thing! And the other wild casts are also suspectible. Why don't you let the compiler help you? Warnings are intended to aid you, not to add another problematic cast.

Comment: What is the point of the main thread start a single other thread and then waiting forever?  If the main thread has nothing else to do then it could and should do its erstwhile child thread's work directly.  You could even get there from here simply by calling the thread's start function directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The memory increases to about 270MB then the server becomes unresponsive

You want to either detach the threads created or join them.

As it stands each thread which ended is zombiing around with all its resource (stack and book keeping data) still being allocated. This eats up the server's memory.

To have a thread detach, have it call

```
pthread_detach(pthread_self());
```

before it ends.

To join a thread have any other thread call `pthread_join()` passing the thread-id as returned by `pthread_create()`.

As the program does not seem to be interested in the threads' results, detaching them might be the preferred solution.

---

There are other issues with the code, which are unrelated to the resource leak:

- how the code handles the result of `recv()`.
- error checking for most relevant function calls is missing.
- `new_sock = malloc(1);` allocates to few memory for an `int` as `new_sock` is.
- `c` should be of type `socklen_t`. Using the casting hammer on its address does not make things better

Comment: As a general rule, I would suggest that parent threads detach their child threads when indeed they are to be detached, instead of threads detaching themselves.  That way, the parent gets to choose between detaching them and joining them, and the thread in question doesn't need to know or care which.